# How to keep white space as

Tags: xml, xslt, printing, xhtml, xslt-1.0

I have xml element as following.

```
<requestBody type="String"><![CDATA[Today, the XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX (#XXXXXXX) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Thanks,

XXXXXXXXXX
Test Administrator

XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX
#### Address
CITY, ST  12345
Direct:  123-123-1234
Main Office:   123-123-1234
Fax:   123-123-1234
E-mail:   XXXXXXXXXX



Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book, please visit www.WEBADDRESS.com<http://www.WEBADDRESS.com>.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.]]>
</requestBody>
```

When I apply `<xsl:value-of select="/requestBody"/>` it is removing all white spaces in this element and printing a concatenated string as:

```
Today, the XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX (#XXXXXXX) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Thanks, XXXXXXXXXX Test Administrator XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX #### Address CITY, ST 12345 Direct: 123-123-1234 Main Office: 123-123-1234 Fax: 123-123-1234 E-mail: XXXXXXXXXX Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book, please visit www.WEBADDRESS.com<http://www.WEBADDRESS.com>. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

Can somebody tell me how to get the element content as-is without removing white spaces?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at [xsl:preserve-space](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_preserve-space.asp)?

Comment: You do not present a well-formed XML element -- there is no start tag, and it looks like the content is supposed to contain a CDATA section, but there is no opening delimiter for that, either.

Comment: In any event, I think you are mis-characterizing the problem.  `xsl:value-of` does not remove or compress whitespace as you describe, but all runs of one or more literal whitespace characters mean the same as a single space *in [X]HTML* in the bodies of most elements.  I think yours is a rendering problem, not an XSLT problem.  You could consider having your transform put the text into a `<pre>` element if you need to preserve the text formatting.

Comment: It has <requestBody> tag at start.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the opening tag and CDATA start was there, but the formatting was borked so they weren't rendering.  I've fixed that.

Comment: @Eiríkr Útlendi can you post your fix here. Thank you!

Comment: @Harishfysx, I've replied with an answer.  Regarding the formatting or your own post, apparently my edit is in a queue and must be approved before anyone besides me can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harishfysx, as John Bollinger notes in the comments, it is unclear if you are describing the actual file output, or the rendering in a browser -- since you include the `xhtml` tag, we (the readers) must assume that you're potentially talking about browser on-screen rendering, which does ignore whitespace in some important ways.

If you *are* talking about the file output, either your code or your XSL processor is doing something funny.  If I apply the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="requestBody">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

... I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Today, the XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX (#XXXXXXX) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Thanks,

XXXXXXXXXX
Test Administrator

XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX
#### Address
CITY, ST  12345
Direct:  123-123-1234
Main Office:   123-123-1234
Fax:   123-123-1234
E-mail:   XXXXXXXXXX



Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book, please visit www.WEBADDRESS.com&lt;http://www.WEBADDRESS.com&gt;.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

You'll note that all whitespace is preserved.

You'll also note that there's that pesky XML header, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, and that the tag-ish link marker `<http://www.WEBADDRESS.com>` in your source is output in escaped format as `&lt;http://www.WEBADDRESS.com&gt;`.  Both of these can be fixed by adding the following before the template:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

Since I can quite easily produce output with whitespace preserved, I must assume that your problem is **not** the XSL, and instead that your browser is displaying this text in the default browser mode, which collapses **each and every** whitespace string (multiple instances of space, tab, newline) into a single space character.

As John suggests, use a `<pre>` element, or use CSS that defines a style of `whitespace:pre;`, if you want strict layout where lines run off the right end of the screen, or `whitespace:pre-wrap;`, if you want to keep the whitespace but have the browser wrap lines that are too long to display within the margins.

Comment: Thank you Eiríkr Útlend,John Bollinger & all ...You guys are awesome.